# Not able to read data from excel using OLEDB

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb, database-engine

I got a code in which it is trying to read data from excel using OLEDB and populate the same into grid view. The grid was not populating with the values as desired. I debugged the code and I am getting a message like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccXKf.jpg)

I have installed Microsoft access database engine 2007 still it's not working. Please help me with this.

Comment: are you sure you are running the same bit-ness as the ACE driver? If you have the 32-bit driver installed, but are running the program in 64-bit it will not work.

Comment: seems related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898597/oledbconnection-open-throws-exception-only-in-one-project-same-code-works-in

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-quotthe-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local?forum=vstsdb